# Jenkins Job DSL, view creation not working properly

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to create a list view via Groovy code for the Jenkins Job DSL plugin.  After the run, the view is created, but no jobs are ever added.  The code before the following snippet creates the build and deploy jobs, and I have verified that they are properly created before calling the view creation code.  My code looks like the following.   What am I missing?

```
def viewName = "${appName}"
listView(viewName) {
  jobs {
    name(buildJobName)
    name(deployJobName)
  }
}
```

Comment: post a minimal, but complete script that reproduces the problem

Comment: `def myJobName              = "ZZmy_test_job"
def viewNameWithoutColumns = "${myJobName}_view_without_columns"
def viewNameWithColumns    = "${myJobName}_view_with_columns"

freeStyleJob(myJobName) {
  steps {
    shell("echo 'hello world'")
  }
}

listView(viewNameWithoutColumns) {
  jobs {
    name(myJobName)
  }
}

listView(viewNameWithColumns) {
  jobs {
    name(myJobName)
  }
  columns {
    status()
    weather()
    name()
    lastSuccess()
    lastFailure()
    lastDuration()
    buildButton()
  }
}`

Comment: Apparently, the mini markdown is not working.  The above script recreates my problem.   It creates two views, one with the columns specified, and one with out.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I finally figured it out:  Apparently, if you do not include the columns list, it will create the view with your jobs you added, but NOT DISPLAY THEM.  Seems like a bug, because the view is useless, until you edit and check the columns you want to display.  Adding the columns list fixed this.

```
listView(viewName) {
  jobs {
    names(buildJobName, deployJobName)
  }
  columns {
    status()
    weather()
    name()
    lastSuccess()
    lastFailure()
    lastDuration()
    buildButton()
    // ...
  }
```

}

Answer (score -2):

looking at the syntax for [listView](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory.listView) you aren't allowed a repeating name tag.
Something like this should work.

```
def viewName = "${appName}"
listView(viewName) {
  jobs {
    names("myDeployJob", "myBuildJob")
  }
}
```

Comment: `name` can be called multiple times to add more jobs to a view, see [name](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory.listView-jobs-name).